# chaining functions on Swift

Tags: swift, chaining

I recently started out to learning Swift which is completely different from my previous work perspective. I found it is interesting like doing the quiz when I am writing the codes..But I have been struggling with this puzzle for a couple of hours now and will be very much appreciate if any of you could help me out..
here is the quiz, and my code below(it looks ridiculous and I have no idea what to do)
the question

[image]

what I wrote

[image]

Comment: Please don't link out to images -- put all of the information in your question.

Comment: You need to add strings together like `"hello " + noun`.  But in Swift, we usually do `"Hello \(noun), I have a \(color) balloon"` -- you call a function by giving the arguments after the argument name so `madLib(noun: noun)` or `madLib(noun: "book")`, not `madLib(noun: String)` which is for defining funcs, not calling them

Comment: thanks for this and the tip..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue is how you inserted the `adverb`, `adjective` and `pluralNoun` into the string. Try this it works fine.

```
func generator(adverb: String, adjective: String, pluralNoun: String) -> String {
  return "Whew! I've been \(adverb) learning how to build \(adjective) app with Udacity. I hope they teach me about \(pluralNoun) soon. That would be helpful."
}
```